# Jquery post array data to asp.net page: Not able to retrieve the array at page load event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Using jQuery ajax post I am posting the array variable to the asp.net page. But I'm not able to retrieve the array variable in the page load event..

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var importTable = $("#dataTables-example");
        var arrayOfValues = [];
        $('#btnDownload').click(function () {
            $('input:checkbox:checked', importTable).each(function () {
                debugger;
                arrayOfValues.push($(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text());
            }).get();

            $.post('CS.aspx', { arrayOfValues: arrayOfValues }, function (data) { });
        });
    });
```

My page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        string emptyStringArray = Request.Params["arrayOfValues1"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Request.Params["arrayOfValues"]

Comment: i think your param name is  "arrayOfValues" not "arrayOfValues1"

Comment: I am still getting null values for emptyStringArray even after changing from Request.Params["arrayOfValues1"] to Request.Params["arrayOfValues"].

Answer (score 0):

Check count for Request variables.

Comment: I have resolved the issue.Instead of the post request I have used get request and hiddenfield.